# Question regarding screen sizes

Tags: google-play, screen-size, android

I'm working on a live wallpaper and ready to
release a new version on the Android market.
Last time when I tested it on a tablet (x-large) screen the images got
cut off and did not scale so i want to disable support for tablets.
Does anyone know how I can do that? I already changed the API level but
it seems I cannot lower that anymore with newer versions.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Take a look [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html). You can set supported screen sizes in your manifest.

```
<supports-screens android:xlargeScreens="false" />
```

Comment: After I added this in my manifest its still showing up to download on tablets :(

Comment: Some tablets are considered largeScreens and not xlargeScreens.